# vb.net Variables Getting Reset

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, boolean, reset

I am trying to reference a boolean variable in VBNet on another form but it is getting reset whenever I reference it.  For example on FORM1:

```
Dim flag as boolean = false
```

and then somewhere I set it to true
Then when I call it from another form:

if FORM1.flag = true then.....

but then it goes to from1 and resets the flag to false.

How can I get my flag not to reset?

Thanks

Comment: You're accessing Form1 via the default instance, which is most likely **not** the same instance that is being displayed.  You need a reference to the correct instance.  Either pass that instance to your other Form, or communicate the fact that the state needs to be change via some other means (like the other Form raising a custom event that Form1 has subscribed to).

Comment: Standard VB.NET trap, that code runs on a worker thread so creates a *new* instance of the form object.  One you cannot see because its Show() method was never called.  Learning the distinction between types (like Form1) and object references can be a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

When you reference a variable in an external form and that form is not loaded, an instance of the form will automatically be loaded, and you can end up with two instances of the same form loaded. This can cause weird problems like you mentioned.

One simple way to use a global variable like `flag` is to create a module (Project, Add Module) and declare `flag` in that module.

Alternatives would be to make sure only one instance of form1 is loaded at a time, or use a parameter or class property to communicate between forms.